# How do I get the target of Control Click in NSOutlineView

Tags: nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

I have a NSOutlineView controlled by a NSTreeController.
NSOutlineView is connected to a Contextual Menu in Interface Builder.

Control Click brings up my Menu, and the row clicked on is "selected" with a pale highlight with a border.

I can't seem to find any way to find which row is "selected".
selectionIndexPath and selectedObjects are nil.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `clickedRow`.  Note that this becomes a bit more complicated if you support multiple selection, because the selection gets targeted by the shortcut menu if the clicked row is within it, whereas if you click elsewhere, the (single) clicked row is the target and the selection is ignored.

Here's an example of some code I wrote to handle this:

```
- (NSArray *)selectedURLs;
{
    NSInteger clickedRow = [outlineView clickedRow];
    NSArray *selectedObjects;

    if (clickedRow == -1 || [[outlineView selectedRowIndexes] containsIndex:clickedRow])
        selectedObjects = [treeController selectedObjects];
    else
        selectedObjects = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[outlineView itemAtRow:clickedRow] representedObject]];

    return [selectedObjects valueForKey:SSTreeNodeAttributes.fileReferenceURL];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I gave up on NSOutlineView and wrote my own data sources etc. This let me override `- (NSMenu *)menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
 NSPoint pt = [self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
 focusedItem = [self itemAtRow: [self rowAtPoint:pt]];
 return [self menu];   
}`